# Linking embedded Svg in Xsl-Fo Pdf

Tags: xslt, svg, xsl-fo, apache-fop, batik

I'm playing with Xml--xslt-->xsl-fo-->pdf and I'm finding a way to include reference inside sub-block of svg image to have the possibility to link to them from other part of the document.

Actually I'm using **Saxon** to trasform the xml to xsl-fo and then Fop (that uses Batik for Svg conversion).

I tought it was easy, as svg is xml, and I've tried to put some id to some  or  block and refers with link to internal destination function of xsl-fo but fop is unable to solve the reference.

Any Idea of how it can be done?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to link to a specific part of the image? If the user views the PDF as e.g. a full page, he won't be able to see which part of the image you have linked to.

Comment: Every SVG is a matlab model. My target is to create an index with all the variable contained in multiple pictures with links to them.

Comment: The reason I'm asking is, would it be sufficient to refer to the fo:block that contains the equation instead of a specific part of the equation. svg may be xml, but it's not XSL-FO so I suspect an FO command inside an SVG won't work.

Comment: Many XSL FO products support the rendering of SVG but not interactive links within them. Check the batik manual and see but I suspect the answer is not supported.

Comment: Have you tried `background-image="url(path/to/file.svg)"` for an element, then create links on foreground.